Error While using resizeboxx for a tikz plot
My code  is expected to plot a function and a tangent, but I am getting an error. The idea is that if I  removed resize box with its closure curly bracket, the plot goes fine, when I add it, I get this error:
Argument of \pgfplots@addplotimpl@expression@curly has an extra }.
I have been trying to detect  the problem days ago, but I did not succeed.
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\font\tenBbb=msbm10
\usepackage[lmargin=2 cm,rmargin=2
cm,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2.5cm,
paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfplots,pgfarrows,pgfnodes,pgfautomata,pgfheaps,pgfshade}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pifont}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumerate}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, arrows, calc,through,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \resizebox{12cm}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                xlabel={$x$},
                ylabel={$y$},
                xmin=-9.75, xmax=19.75,
                ymin=-9.75, ymax=25,
                domain=-6:15,
                samples=100,
                axis lines=middle,
                xtick = {-8,-6,-4,...,14,16},
                ytick = {-8,-6,-4,...,20,22},
                grid=both,
                grid style={dotted}
                %width=10cm,
                %height=8cm,
                ]
                \addplot[ thick]{-2 + (x + 4)*exp(-x)};
                \addplot[blue, thick]{-3*x+2};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture} }   
    \end{center}
    \end{document} 


Why have you commented lines of width and height? This is the recommended approach to re-scale plots, besides scale and other useful options (see p. 295 or secion 4.10 Scaling options of the documentation). Even if \resizebox worked, it's hardly useful because the outcome is unpredictable. it should only be the last resort, when anything else failed. The same applies to tikz, tables, graphics, etc. Always search package manuals and use recommended options.
